# How can I write the names of variables as value labels into another variable in R?

Tags: r, loops, label

I am fairly new to R. This is my test-dataframe.

```
test_df<-data.frame(QID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
                    ABC_ABC=c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0),
                    DEF_DEF=c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
                    GHJ_GHJ=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0),
                    None=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1),
                    model=c(1,2,1,1,3,1,4))
```

What I am trying to do is to add value labels to test_df$model. The value labels should be added as the names of the columns. So end-result should be for test_df$model:

- n=1, value 1 is labelled "ABC_ABC"
- n=2, value 2 is labelled "DEF_DEF"
- n=3, value 1 is labelled "ABC_ABC"
- n=4, value 1 is labelled "ABC_ABC"
- n=5, value 3 is labelled "GHJ_GHJ"
- n=6, value 1 is labelled "ABC_ABC"
- n=7, value 4 is labelled "None"

My real dataset is much bigger and variables are regularly changing in names and positions, therefore I need to do it in an "automated" way, where it pulls the column names as value labels.

I tried working with for loops, but I could not make it work (I also read a lot of times, that in R other functions like `sapply`, `lapply`, etc. should be used instead of loops, but I cannot figure a way).

If any other code is needed to fully understand my problem, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the column names via names() and then use the index in the model-column (+1 because QID should be neglected) to create a new column or to overwrite the model-column:

```
test_df$model <- names(test_df)[test_df$model+1]
test_df$model
[1] "ABC_ABC" "DEF_DEF" "ABC_ABC" "ABC_ABC" "GHJ_GHJ" "ABC_ABC" "None"
```

New column creation would be :
`test_df$newColumn <- names(test_df)[test_df$model+1]`

Answer (score 0):

```r
df<-data.frame(QID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
               ABC_ABC=c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0),
               DEF_DEF=c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
               GHJ_GHJ=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0),
               None=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1),
               model=c(1,2,1,1,3,1,4))

nm <- names(df)[-c(1, 6)]
index <- apply(df[, -c(1, 6)], 1, which.max)
df$model_name <- nm[index]

df
#>   QID ABC_ABC DEF_DEF GHJ_GHJ None model model_name
#> 1   1       1       0       0    0     1    ABC_ABC
#> 2   2       0       1       0    0     2    DEF_DEF
#> 3   3       1       0       0    0     1    ABC_ABC
#> 4   4       1       0       0    0     1    ABC_ABC
#> 5   5       0       0       1    0     3    GHJ_GHJ
#> 6   6       1       0       0    0     1    ABC_ABC
#> 7   7       0       0       0    1     4       None
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>